# Order by date always uses filesort

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, filesort

I have the following table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `number` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `revision` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `autosave` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `blob` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `number_revision_autosave` (`number`, `revision`, `autosave`) USING BTREE,

    -- The following was not there originally but my attempt to solve my own issue
    UNIQUE INDEX `number_revision_autosave_created_at` (`number`, `revision`, `autosave`, `created_at`) USING BTREE 
);
```

the blob column can potentially be large(ish). On average it's about 20kb but can be much larger (there's no real upper limit, but a practical limit of 20-30mb can be assumed).

When I use a query like this:

```sql
select *
from test
WHERE `number` = 1 
    AND autosave=0
order by `revision` desc
```

everything is working great

However if I use:

```sql
select *
from test

-- This is also my attempt at a solution
USE INDEX (number_revision_autosave_created_at)

WHERE `number` = 1 
    AND autosave=0
order by `created_at` desc
```

I sometimes get `Error "1038 Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size`

After a bit of looking into it the notable difference is that the explain of the 1st query is showing: `Using where; Backward index scan` in the extras while the second one is showing `Using index condition; Using filesort`

The "out of sort memory error" started making more sense at this point because my sort buffer size was 256kb and the result set contained single rows that were larger than this.

In my attempt to solve this I created an index which included `created_at` i.e.

```
UNIQUE INDEX `number_revision_autosave_created_at` (`number`, `revision`, `autosave`, `created_at`) USING BTREE
```

Then tried to "persuade" MySQL to use that one by doing `USE INDEX (number_revision_autosave_created_at)` however, while MySQL did actually use this index, it still opted to do a filesort.

For now I have increased to sort buffer size to about 30mb, to cover these edge cases, but this is not an ideal (or future proof) solution.

I am not sure what I can do to make it use an index scan like in the previous case. What is the problem here? Default table engine is InnoDB and I am using MySQL Community version 8.0.32

Comment: number - autosave - created at index may help. Your indexes have the revision column in them that renders your indexes unusable beyond the column.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, that does actually seem to work, but now I am puzzled as to why the same doesn't apply if I did `order by created_at desc, revision desc` if I didn't modify the index

Comment: Add revision to the end of the index.

Comment: @Shadow That does answer my question, in case you want to post it as an answer

Comment: Please keep in mind that *filesort* isn't always as slow as it sounds. It actually means the DBMS is sorting an internal temporary table data structure. It doesn't always spill to an actual file-system file unless it must. (In your case it probably did.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of columns in an index matters as mysql can only proced to use columns starting from left one after the other.

Your indexes include `revision` column at the 2nd position from left, but this column is not included in the where clause at the 2nd position. This means, your indexes can only be used by the sample queries to filter on the `number` column.

Ad an index with this exact order of columns to speed the queries up in your question: number - autosave - created_at